# How to deploy Java EE application using Jenkins CI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins CI configured with a SVN repo of our Java EE based application.

I am able to build the application but I am facing problems while deploying the war. Actually I don't have any idea how to get a war file out of the build and deploy it to a remote Tomcat 7 server.

I need to deploy this code to Tomcat 7 in the form of a war deployment. Please guide me through any tutorial or docs.

Comment: This might help : http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/03/21/integrating-jenkins-and-apache-tomcat-continuous-deployment

Comment: Try a plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

If your build is Maven based, you could use the [Maven Tomcat plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html). This will do more or less the same actions as the [Jenkins Deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin), but it will add a dependency on your build tool and not on your continuous integration tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for that: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Basically, the deploy plugin will use tomcat's built in [REST API/manager application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to deploy the war file.

I use this in anger, and it's pretty simple. The plugin does everything you'll need for a simple situation.

If your needs are more complicated than this, you can script access to the management REST API directly, but I advise you to start with the plugin.